# Angular 8 Mat-Autocomplete inside ngFor just showing on the last item

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular8

I'm doing a custom form with a FormArray in Angular 8 and in every position i have an Autocomplete as an Input, but the behavior is not what i expected. It just shows up on the las position input.

Code:

```
<div formArrayName="assignments" *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('assignments')['controls']; let i = index;">
    <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">                       
           <mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
                <mat-label>{{ 'product.providers.txt.provider' | translate}}</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput formControlName="id_provider"[matAutocomplete]="providers">
                <mat-autocomplete #providers="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayPv">
                     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions[i] | async" [value]="option.id">
                         {{option.provider_business_name}}
                     </mat-option>
                 </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
     </ng-container>
</div>
```

Here is an example:

[image: Text]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: I cannot replicate the same example but its basically an Angular Material Autocomplete inside a Form Array that just only works with the last input of that FormArray, maybe it looses its focus or it isnt mean to be used inside a formArray!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was receiving the data from an API, i wasn't adding the control on each loop, here is how i solved it!

```
setExistingAssignments(assignmentsSet) {
        const control = this.myForm.get('assignments') as FormArray;

        assignmentsSet.forEach(s => {
            control.push(this.fb.group({
                // Some assignaments
            }));
            this.ManageNameControl(control.length - 1); // This is the function
        });

        this.available = true;
        return control;
    }

// The function
ManageNameControl(index: number) {
        const arrayControl = this.myForm.get('assignments') as FormArray;

        if (arrayControl.length > 0) {
            this.filteredOptions[index] = arrayControl.at(index).get('id_provider').valueChanges
                .pipe(
                    startWith<string>(''),
                    map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value['id_provider']),
                    map(name => name ? this._filter(name, 'provider') : this.options.slice())
                );
        }

    }
```

So the function before was outside the loop! Now it's inside so on each position it will add a control and a search for that row!

Thank you very much!